# Showing a container in a v-for based on outcome of method that is called each iteration

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I'm quite new to Vue and I'm running into a problem that I can't wrap my head around.

I have a for loop in Vue. For every iteration, I want to call a method to check if the item belonging to the iteration is in an array. If not: I'm adding it to the array. If it's already there, the method returns false.

Seems pretty straight forward to me, BUT. It seems that for each iteration only the last outcome of the method is being shown.

The method by itself seems to work fine: console.log returns the correct values. I assume that it's not possible to call the method on every for loop like I do, but I don't know why and I don't know how to do it otherwise.

**Vue code**

```
<div v-for="item in this.assertions" v-bind:key="item.assertion">
     <div v-if="showHeader(item.categoryName)">Some text or containers</div>
</div>
```

**Vue method**

```
showHeader(category) {
            if (this.shownHeaders.indexOf(category) === -1) {
                this.shownHeaders.push(category);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        },
```

**Data property**

```
shownHeaders: []
```

I really want to understand how this works!

**EDIT:** **let me adjust my main question a bit: is it possible to call a method every iteration in a for loop and let the method return true or false (each time)?** If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the so-called `reactivity`. Every time a `data` property changes, it triggers the DOM update. Because you are continuously adding new elements into the `shownHeaders` property (if they are not there already), you are causing these updates. These updates stop only after all the elements are already in the array, and that final state will also be reflected in your DOM in the end.

If you really want to understand what's going on, you could read this source: https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/understanding-vue-js-reactivity

Comment: That actually clears it up very well, thank you! But if the updated source is always shows (aka the last update), how would I ever do a check such as this one for every iteration?

Comment: Tell me what your desired behavior is, and we can think of something ;-)

Comment: The header should be shown based on whether a category name is already in the shownHeaders array (or not). This check should then be done every iteration in the for loop.

So for example: Header1 is in the first iteration, so the method adds Header1 to the array and returns true (the header should be shown). Header1 is also in the second iteration. The method finds Header1 to already be in the array, to it returns false (the header should not be shown). 

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Hmm.. It actually still doesn't make complete sense to me. Where / how should this iteration take place ? Can you instead try to explain this from the user perspective?

Comment: Sure! The users see a wizard (with slots). On every slot, questions are being shown. Only the first question should show the title of the category, because otherwise it will show for every question.
I cannot do this with a simple index check, because the index of the first question on the slot isn't always 0. For the second slot it can be any other number (based on how many questions were shown on the first slot. This varies per time and per slot). Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually not :D. If you could prepare a simple example here (even not completely working), I might finally get it: https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg97c0s2/
I don't think this clears it up a lot though. I'm unable to show you a good example because the data comes from my own api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202458/discussion-between-ajobi-and-user3478148).

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to call a method every iteration in a for loop and let the method return true or false (each time)?

Yes, it is perfectly possible

> If so, how?

Exactly how you doing it...

---

Your question doesn't contain exact description of what you expect from your code and exact description of current behaviour neither, so what follows is just guesswork

If it doesn't work as expected, it is not because of method call per se but because what is code in the method doing in context of the component...

The biggest problem I see is your misunderstanding of how template in Vue works. Mainly the fact **the template is rendered every time some of the data it is using is changed**.

It is clear your code is written in a way as if you are expecting the template will be rendered only once. Thanks to `shownHeaders` array, category header will be rendered only first time and hidden next time your component re-renders...

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it seems like you interpreted my question the wrong way. I've adjusted my question, maybe this clears things up about what I actually want to know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this on `templates` try on your methods if your goal is to get the `showHeaders` like below.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click.prevent="showHeader()">Click to show Headers</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            assertions: [],            
            shownHeaders: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showHeader() {
            assertions.forEach((item) => {
                if (this.shownHeaders.indexOf(item.categoryName) === -1) {
                    this.shownHeaders.push(item.categoryName)
                }
            })
        }
    }   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want the visitor to have to click a button first. The header should be shown based on whether a category name is already in the shownHeaders array (or not). This check should then be done by every iteration in the for loop.